# How can I make a UIImage View clickable to segue to another view controller

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift2

I'm new in programming and I'm stuck with this little problem. I created a table view with several items, that passes data to a label and an image view through a segue. It all works fine, but now I want to make the image clickable, in order to segue to another view controller to show this image expanded. How can I do that?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var descLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


    var titleName: String?
    var descName: String?
    var imageName: String?

    func configureView() {
        if let poster = self.imageName {
            if let imagePoster = self.imageView {
                imagePoster.image = UIImage (named: poster)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleLabel.text = titleName
        descLabel.text = descName

        self.configureView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to use a UIButton instead of an image view. Set it's type to custom and install the image into the button in IB (Interface Builder).

That way you can trigger an IBAction just like any other button. It also highlights on a touch like you'd expect, triggers on touch up rather than touch down, etc.

If you don't want to use a button-with-image, you have to set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the image view and install a tap gesture recognizer on it. See the docs on `UITapGestureRecognizer` for more information.